# React Native - Navigation through routestack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I press the second Highlight, it should navigate to the third Scene.
But it navigates to a blank/white screen.
The only way to get to the third scene is only if you go to the second scene by pressing the first highlight, pop, and then press to the second highlight and then it works.
But what if I want to get to the third right away?

```
<Navigator initialRoute={routes[0]} initialRouteStack={routes} renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
    <View>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
      if (route.index == 0) {
        navigator.push(routes[1]);
      } else {
        navigator.pop();
      }
      }
    }
    >
    <Text>Hello {route.title}!</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
      if (route.index == 0) {
          navigator.push(routes[2]);
      } else {
        navigator.pop();
      }
      }
    }
    >
    <Text>Please {route.title}!</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    {getPage(route.index)}
</View>
}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

You need to remove `initialRouteStack` prop from your `Navigator` if you have already set `initialRoute` prop so you are able to navigate to the third scene from the first scene.

Not sure why you can't have both props set for it to work.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to achieve. I want two TouchableHighlights in the First scene. One points to second scene, and one points to the third scene.

Comment: @EGK Updated my answer, I think it should solve your issue. Sorry, I misunderstood the question earlier on.